# More than one Subquery Returned

Tags: mysql

select email, expiration from member where expiration = (select ifnull(email, phone) as 'Contact' from member where expiration >= '2008' and expiration <='2009');

I get more than one subquery returned. Any help?

I am trying to answer this:

We need to get in touch with our members whose expiration is in 2008, we want to use email as the primary means of contact; however, if an email address is not available, we want to know their phone number.

Comment: Why do you have a subquery at all? What's wrong with `select ifnull(email, phone) as 'Contact' from member where expiration >= '2008' and expiration <='2009'`?

Comment: @kba, what's wrong with posting that as answer?

Comment: @Rahul I thought I misunderstood the question. This seemed too obvious. I literally just copied his own subquery.

Comment: @kba, Now see, you missed +15 rep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in instead of = in this kind of situations.

```
select email, expiration 
from member 
where expiration in (select ifnull(email, phone) as 'Contact' from member where expiration >= '2008' and expiration <='2009');
```

But this will not work either. Because you try to compare expiration against email or phone.

The correct query should be something like:

```
select ifnull(email, phone) as 'Contact', expiration 
from member 
where expiration >= '2008' and expiration <='2009';
```